# Scrape brand suggestions from Keepa with Python

Tags: python, sockets, web, websocket, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape brand suggestions from https://keepa.com/#!finder
For example when you're typing 'ni' in field "brand" the list with suggestions appears. It includes all brands started with 'ni' like 'nike'.
[image]

I know that a websocket session is responsible for that. When you press a key, it sends gzipped JSON string to that session and receives response like this.
[image]
So the yellow items are gzipped strings.
When I'm trying to recreate this in Python, it fails.
The following code

```
from websocket import create_connection
import zlib
websocket_resource_url = 'wss://dyn.keepa.com/apps/cloud/?app=keepaWebsite&version=1.6'

ws = create_connection(websocket_resource_url)
msg = {"path":"pro/autocomplete","content":"nike","domainId":1,"maxResults":25,"type":"brand","version":3,"id":111111,"user":"user"}

ws.send(zlib.compress((json.dumps(msg)+'\n').encode('utf-8')))

print('Result: {}'.format(zlib.decompress(ws.recv())))
```

returns `{"status":108, "n":73}`
But expected output is somethins like:

```
{"startTimeStamp":1637576348774,"id":7596,"timeStamp":1637576348774,"status":200,"version":3,"lastUpdate":0,"suggestions":[{"value":"nike","count":1100713},{"value":"nike golf","count":7497},{"value":"nikeelando","count":358},{"value":"nikea","count":195},{"value":"nike sb","count":87}]}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @472084 I have used another way with Selenium, just automated browser, typed brands using frontend, and scraped the results.